# Fourier Sequence Converges Uniformly Implies Almost Everywhere Pointwise Convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to understand this problem:
Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[0,2\pi]$

Suppose that the Fourier Series of $f$, $S_{n}^{f}(x)$, converges uniformly on the interval.

I want to show that $S_{n}^{f}(x)\to f(x)$ point-wise almost everywhere.

My attempt:

Since $S_{n}^{f}(x)$ converges uniformly, and $S_{n}^{f}(x)$ is continuous then it holds that $S_{n}^{f}(x) \to g(x)$ uniformly for $g$ continuous.

Then clearly $S_{n}^{f}(x_{0})$ converges to $g(x_{0})$ everywhere on the interval.

Also, since by definition $\int (S_{n}^{f}(x)-f(x)^2dx \to 0$

then $\int (lim_{n\to \infty}S_{n}^{f}(x)-f(x)^2dx = 0 = \int (g(x)-f(x)^2dx$

thus $g=f$ almost everywhere.

Is this reasoning correct?

thanks!

Comment: Yes, if the series converges uniformly to $g$, then $g$ must be continuous and, therefore, Riemann integrable. Uniform convergence also implies $L^2$ convergence. If you know that the Fourier series converges in $L^2$ to the original function $f$ (which you seem to know based on your proposed solution,) then you know that $f=g$ a.e. because $L^2$ limit functions are unique a.e..